# IPlugEffect (Audio Unit target) "SysError 0 during open of "resource.h""

Tags: c++, osx-mountain-lion, xcode3.2, audiounit

I'm running OSX 10.8 and Xcode 3.2.4, i've tried compiling against both 10.5 & 10.6 to no avail.

I'm using Oli Larkin's framework for compiling audio plug-ins to each vst, vst3, au & rtas. All are working perfectly apart from compiling to Audio Unit. When I attempt to compile I get "SysError 0 during open of "resource.h"". This is happening not only for the duplicate project i've made, but also for the IPlugEffect and IPlugMaxi unchanged examples.

This is the full error Xcode is giving me -

Rez build-mac/MBPressor007.build/Debug/AU_32_intel.build/ResourceManagerResources/Objects/IPlugAU-73B43941A9DFE8A.rsrc ../../WDL/IPlug/IPlugAU.r
cd "/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007"
/Developer/Tools/Rez -o "/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/build-mac/MBPressor007.build/Debug/AU_32_intel.build/ResourceManagerResources/Objects/IPlugAU-73B43941A9DFE8A.rsrc" -d SystemSevenOrLater=1 -useDF -script Roman -d ppc_$ppc -d i386_YES -I /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/Headers -I /Developer/Examples/CoreAudio/AudioUnits/AUPublic/AUBase -arch i386 -i "/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/build-mac/Debug" -i /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/Headers -i /Developer/Examples/CoreAudio/AudioUnits/AUPublic/AUBase -i "/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/../../WDL/swell" -i "/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/../../WDL" -i "/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/../../VST_SDK" -i "/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/../../WDL/IPlug/dfx" -i "/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007" -i "/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/../../WDL/IPlug/RTAS" -i "/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/../../VST3_SDK/public.sdk/source/common" -i "/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/../../VST3_SDK/pluginterfaces/gui" -i "/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/../../VST3_SDK/pluginterfaces/base" -i "/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/../../VST3_SDK/public.sdk/source/vst" -i "/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/../../VST3_SDK/pluginterfaces/vst" -i "/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/app_wrapper" -i "/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/../../WDL/rtaudiomidi" -i "/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/../../VST3_SDK/public.sdk/source/main" -i "/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/build-mac/Debug" -i "/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/build-mac/Debug/include" -i /Developer/Plugin -i SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/../../WDL/IPlug -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk "/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/../../WDL/IPlug/IPlugAU.r"

/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/../../WDL/IPlug/IPlugAU.r:1: ### /Developer/Tools/Rez - SysError 0 during open of "resource.h".
Fatal Error!
/Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/../../WDL/IPlug/IPlugAU.r:1: ### /Developer/Tools/Rez - Fatal Error, can't recover.
resource.h: ### /Developer/Tools/Rez - Since errors occurred, /Developer/Plugin SDKs/olilarkin-wdl-ol-92f9028/IPlugExamples/MBPressor007/build-mac/MBPressor007.build/Debug/AU_32_intel.build/ResourceManagerResources/Objects/IPlugAU-73B43941A9DFE8A.rsrc's resource fork was not written.

The File DEFINITELY exists, and I've tried setting the REZ_SEARCH_PATHS option in the target's build settings to point to the absolute path of my project, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using Xcode3?

Comment: because Xcode 4 was giving me even MORE grief with this current SDK... I think Oli's still to give it a proper upgrade (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Ahhhhh worked it out!!

The issue was that I had installed the SDKs and my projects within the Developer directory, and this was causing some kind of clash... After reinstalling the SDKs and my projects in my user directory, I've no longer had any problems at all. This should work for anyone running into any rez issues regarding seemingly unreadable .h files..